# Adding random number of images inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>` and i want to add images into it. The number of images will vary randomly.

here is what i am trying to do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < = randomnumber; i++) {
            $(this).append(img);
        }
    });
});
```

But it is not working. Please help

here is my code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n49mx/)

Comment: I would recommend providing a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows your problem in action

Comment: What kind of element is your #button? Is it <button>?

Comment: There were a few errors in your fiddle. I corrected them. [**New fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/LJm7f/) :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use clone as simon suggests, or you can create new images:

```
function getImage(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://cdn.acidcow.com/pics/20110830/lolcats_ever_13.jpg"
    img.width = 200;
    return img;
}

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1,
    imgContainer = $("#imgContainer"),
    i;

$("#imgNo").text(rand);

for (i=0; i<rand; i++){
    imgContainer.append(getImage());
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/76uzC/)**

Answer (score 2):

uhm, you aren't defining any new images. I am not sure from where you are getting your images. If you have differeny images, you can use the next loop. Besides that, the `this` points to the `#button` element. Not sure which item it is, but if it's an input button, then it won't work. you have to use a `div` or `article` or `section` ... as target.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        // random number
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
        // insert images
        for (var i = 1; i < = randomnumber; i++) {
            // create a new img - element
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            // give it an id
            img.attr("id","img_" + i);
            // source, link
            img.attr("src","your_URL_here");
            // put newly created image in the div with id yourDivIdHere
            $('#yourDivIdHere').append(img);
        }
    });
});
```

the `id` has to be unique, that's why i'm using the index of the for loop for the `id` of the newly created element. Having same `id` for multiple HTML elements can lead to issues.

`#yourDivIdHere` means the div with the id `yourDivIdHere`, like

```
<div id="yourDivIdHere"></div>
```

When you are re-using the button, simply clear the content by using `$('#yourDivIdHere').empty()` method if you don't want to see that old images are still there after clicking on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the image:

```
$(this).append( $(img).clone() );
```

Your way always puts the same image (only one instance!) inside of div random amount of times. So in the end it is only one image.

If you clone it every time then you will have N amount of images

Comment: inside loop if any alert i am doing then it is not showing. what should i do it to make it work

Comment: I can't imagine OP wants to use `this` as that will mean the `#button` element is what gets appended to...

Answer (score -1):

You are getting elements by id, so appended element is always the same element with id="img". Read about [jQuery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all  elements.

Comment: The issue is not with the retrieval of the `img` element. It is about how it is used, which you answer does not help solve